# Changing order of an array in mongoose does not save

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using drag and drop library to change the order of my elements, and I need that order to be saved, the following method does change the document but it won't save it, I tried doc.save() and this update method, the logged doc is in changed order but it's not updated in the database.

```
module.exports.changeListOrder = async(req, res) => {
        const { id, listID, oldIndex, newIndex } = req.body;
        await Board.findById(id).then(async(doc) => {
            let tmpdoc = doc.lists[oldIndex];
            doc.lists[oldIndex] = doc.lists[newIndex];
            doc.lists[newIndex] = tmpdoc;
            await Board.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: { list: doc.lists } })
    
        });
    }
```

and my model has

```
lists: [{ header: String, listItems: Array }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up Promise and async syntax. The async syntax would be like this:

```
module.exports.changeListOrder = async (req, res) => {
    const { id, listID, oldIndex, newIndex } = req.body;
    const thisBoard = await Board.findById(id);
    
    // this code won't run until thisBoard has returned a value
    let [oldValue, newValue] = [thisBoard.lists[oldIndex], thisBoard.lists[newIndex];
    thisBoard[oldIndex] = newValue;
    thisBoard[newIndex] = oldValue;

    let saveOperation = await Board.save(thisBoard);
    
    // console.log(saveOperation);
    // return saveOperation or do something with res()

};
```

Comment: you have a lot of mistakes that I edited but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports.changeListOrder = async(req, res) => {
    const { id, listID, oldIndex, newIndex } = req.body;
    const doc = await Board.findById(id);

    let [oldValue, newValue] = [doc.lists[oldIndex], doc.lists[newIndex]];

    doc.lists.set(oldIndex, newValue);
    doc.lists.set(newIndex, oldValue);

    await doc.save();
};
```

Here is the working code, the problem was that Mongoose doesn't create getters/setters for array indexes; without them mongoose never gets notified of the change and so doesn't know to persist the new value, so you have to use set()